# Array stored in a string type : PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Today i faced weird problem it is

```
$stringvar = '["image_link1","Image_link2"]';
```

Now i want to covert it into type array,
    like

```
Array => [0] Image_link1, [1] Image_link2
```

I tried to juggling the type but it's giving me

```
Array => [0] '["image_link1","Image_link2"]'
```

Right now I am using
`str_replace()` to replace `'['`, `']'` with blank. then explode.

Is there any best workaround for it?

Comment: That string format is JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is formatted in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) notation.

PHP offers the convenient function [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode that:

```
<?php
$stringvar = '["image_link1","Image_link2"]';
print_r(json_decode($stringvar));
```

The output of the above script is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => image_link1
    [1] => Image_link2
)
```

Comment: JSON uses curly braces for objects and square braces for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try your code but at first it looked weird for mee too.
I believe you can get rid off the apostrophes here $stringvar = '["image_link1","Image_link2"]';
so it gives you :

```
$stringvar = ["image_link1","Image_link2"];
```

This should work or you can also try :

```
$stringvar = array("image_link1","Image_link2");
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: LOL, this is good thinking! I doubt that is the OPs issue, more likely he receives the string from some API or similar out of his control. But it certainly is good to point this out! +1

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't understand the question that way. So then, you're right json_decode(); will do the trick ;)